# Integration of realsense d435i camera and openvins

Tags: ros, ros2, intel

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, I am updating my question, I am trying to integrate the realsense d435i camera and openvins nodes in one launch file in ROS2 Foxy. I have converted the openvins node into a composable node and am running it with the realsense composable node in a single container, the launch file runs and the opevins node subscribes to the camera and imu topics but still I don't see any output on /trackhist or /odomimu. If anybody has worked on this before and encountered this issue, please help me out. Here is the launch file -

```
import os
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory, get_package_prefix
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, LogInfo, OpaqueFunction
from launch.conditions import IfCondition
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration, TextSubstitution
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch_ros.actions import ComposableNodeContainer
from launch_ros.descriptions import ComposableNode

def generate_launch_description():

    # Define launch arguments
    launch_args = [
        DeclareLaunchArgument(name="namespace", default_value="ov_msckf", description="namespace"),
        DeclareLaunchArgument(name="ov_enable", default_value="true", description="enable OpenVINS node"),
        DeclareLaunchArgument(name="rviz_enable", default_value="false", description="enable rviz node"),
        DeclareLaunchArgument(name="config", default_value="rs435i", description="euroc_mav, tum_vi, rpng_aruco..."),
        DeclareLaunchArgument(name="config_path", default_value="", description="path to estimator_config.yaml. If not given, determined based on provided 'config' above"),
        DeclareLaunchArgument(name="verbosity", default_value="INFO", description="ALL, DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, SILENT"),
        DeclareLaunchArgument(name="use_stereo", default_value="true", description="if we have more than 1 camera, if we should try to track stereo constraints between pairs"),
        DeclareLaunchArgument(name="max_cameras", default_value="2", description="how many cameras we have 1 = mono, 2 = stereo, >2 = binocular (all mono tracking)"),
        DeclareLaunchArgument(name="save_total_state", default_value="false", description="record the total state with calibration and features to a txt file"),
    ]

    config_path = os.path.join(
        get_package_share_directory('ov_msckf'),
        'config', 'rs_d435', 'estimator_config.yaml')

    # Config file
    config_file = os.path.join(
        get_package_share_directory('argos_launch'),
        'config', 'sensors', 'realsense_ov.yaml')

    realsense_node = ComposableNode(
        namespace="camera",
        package='realsense2_camera',
        plugin='realsense2_camera::RealSenseNodeFactory',
        parameters=[config_file],
        remappings = [("/camera/imu", "/imu0"),
                  ("/camera/infra1/image_rect_raw", "/cam1/image_raw"),
                  ("/camera/infra2/image_rect_raw", "/cam0/image_raw")]
    )

    open_vins_node = ComposableNode(     
        package='ov_msckf',
        plugin='ov_msckf::OpenVinsNode',
        parameters=[
        {"verbosity": LaunchConfiguration("verbosity")},
        {"use_stereo": LaunchConfiguration("use_stereo")},
        {"max_cameras": LaunchConfiguration("max_cameras")},
        {"save_total_state": LaunchConfiguration("save_total_state")},
        #{"config_path": config_path},
        ],
    )
    
    container = ComposableNodeContainer(
        name='my_container',
        namespace='',
        package='rclcpp_components',
        executable='component_container',
        composable_node_descriptions=[
            realsense_node,
            open_vins_node,
        ],
        output='screen',
    )

    ld = LaunchDescription(launch_args)
    ld.add_action(container)

    return ld
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/417426/integration-of-realsense-d435i-camera-and-openvins/) by [Robo_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/90798/robo_guy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2023-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved this issue by myself, turns out there was issue with the correct use of namespace for the composable nodes and also how the parameters need to be read from the configuration yaml file.

---

Originally posted by [Robo_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/90798/robo_guy/) with karma: 115 on 2023-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0